# Jquery $.map function giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following code to map events to FullCalendar

```
 events: function(start, end, callback)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "Calendar.aspx/GetEvents",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        var events = [];

                         $.map(response.d, function (item) {
                            var event = new Object();
                            event.id = item.EventID;
                            event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                            event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                            event.title = item.EventName;
                            return event;
                            events.push(event);
                         })
                         callback(events);
                    },

                    error: function (err) {
                       alert('Error');
                    }
                });
             },
```

The Calendar.aspx/GetEvents function returns the following data successfully:

```
"[{"EventID":1,"EventName":"EventName 1","StartDate":"04-04-2014","EndDate":"04-06-2014"},{"EventID":2,"EventName":"EventName 2","StartDate":"04-08-2014","EndDate":"04-09-2014"},{"EventID":3,"EventName":"EventName 3","StartDate":"04-14-2014","EndDate":"04-15-2014"},{"EventID":4,"EventName":"EventName 4","StartDate":"04-26-2014","EndDate":"04-29-2014"}]"
```

I want to iterate through this data and assign it to the calendar.

My above $map function gives me the following error:

**Cannot use in operator to search for 352 in [{"EventID":1,"EventName":"EventName 1","StartDate":"04-04-2014","EndDate**

How can I do this??

Comment: `return event;` ??????

Comment: I too was wondering about the same @Satpal and the code after that will not execute

Comment: $.map expects the input to be an array or object, you are giving it a string.

Comment: Also this is not a valid json string, so you cannot parse it.

Comment: HI thanks for the replies, I'm so new to json so apologies.  Can I convert the string to a valid array?

Comment: Can you try to remove contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', your data are already get as JSON because of dataType: 'json' a demo works here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/mTQU4/

Comment: I made the following changes 1. Modified the GetEvents to return an array. 2. Removed the return event (mybad ). 3. Removed the  charset=utf-8. It now works thanks guys

Comment: @RickLancee: Why do you think it isn't valid JSON? And why do you think `$.map` is being given a string?

Comment: @HarryBoy: You're still using `$.map` incorrectly. The point of it is that it *creates* an Array, so there's no need to create one before the loop and `.push()` into it. You should keep the `return` statement, remove the `.push`, and do `var events = $.map(response.d, func...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're  using `$.map` incorrectly. The point of it is that it *creates* an Array, so there's no need to create one before the loop and `.push()` into it.

You should keep the `return` statement, remove the `.push`, and set the return value of `$.map` to the `events` variable.

```
success: function (response) {
    var events = $.map(response.d, function (item) {
        var event = new Object();
        event.id = item.EventID;
        event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
        event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
        event.title = item.EventName;
        return event;
     });
     callback(events);
},
```

---

However, object literal syntax is nicer.

```
success: function (response) {
    var events = $.map(response.d, function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.EventID,
            start: new Date(item.StartDate),
            end: new Date(item.EndDate),
            title: item.EventName,
        };
     });
     callback(events);
},
```

---

The error message shown in your question doesn't seem to make sense for the code provided.